# Silverlight Business Application OOB - All content disapears after lost focus

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-oob

I have an out-of-browser app started from the Silverlight Business Application template. About 1 second after the app launches, **all the content inside the application dissapears**. The only detail i can give is that in the output window, right before the content dissapears, two assemblies get loaded:

```
'sllauncher.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\en-US\System.Windows.debug.resources.dll'
'sllauncher.exe' (Silverlight): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'
```

Does anyone have any idea where this problem can come from?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem, the application was throwing an exception, which was not caught. If i marked the exception as handled in the `Application_UnhandledException` event, it worked fine.